# Increase LabelField value as slider is moved

Tags: blackberry, slider, gauge

I have created a SliderField class in order to show a drag-able slider in my BlackBerry application. The slider is basically used to set interval for location updates (via GPS) in the app. The app is built on OS 5.0 and so no API was found for the SliderField. The problem 
I am facing is that I need to increase the integer value in a label as the slider is moved. For instance, if the integer value in a label is 1 and the user moves the slider the value should increase to 5,10,15 etc. I do not know how to link moving the slider to increasing the value in the label field. Can anyone please help? I am adding the SliderField object to the screen as below:

```
Bitmap sliderBack = Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "progress51.png" );
    Bitmap sliderFocus = Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "progress51.png" );
    Bitmap sliderThumb = Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "butt.png" );
SliderField theSlider = new SliderField( sliderThumb, sliderBack, sliderFocus,20, 1, 1, 1 );
         secondHFM.add(theSlider)
```

Below is my code for the SliderField class.

```
public class SliderField extends Field
 {
 Bitmap _imageThumb;

Bitmap _imageSlider;
Bitmap _imageSliderLeft;
Bitmap _imageSliderCenter;
Bitmap _imageSliderRight;

Bitmap _imageSliderFocus;
Bitmap _imageSliderFocusLeft;
Bitmap _imageSliderFocusCenter;
Bitmap _imageSliderFocusRight;

private int _numStates;
private int _currentState;
private boolean _selected;

private int _xLeftBackMargin;
private int _xRightBackMargin;

private int _thumbWidth;
private int _thumbHeight;

private int _totalHeight;
private int _totalWidth;

private int _rop;

private int _backgroundColours[];
private int _backgroundSelectedColours[];

private int _defaultSelectColour = 0x977DED;
private int _defaultBackgroundColour = 0x000000;
private int _defaultHoverColour = 0x999999;


public SliderField( Bitmap thumb
            , Bitmap sliderBackground
            , int numStates
            , int initialState
            , int xLeftBackMargin
            , int xRightBackMargin )
{
    this( thumb, sliderBackground, sliderBackground, numStates, initialState, xLeftBackMargin, xRightBackMargin, FOCUSABLE );
}

public SliderField( Bitmap thumb
            , Bitmap sliderBackground
            , int numStates
            , int initialState
            , int xLeftBackMargin
            , int xRightBackMargin
            , long style )
{  
    this( thumb, sliderBackground, sliderBackground, numStates, initialState, xLeftBackMargin, xRightBackMargin, style );
}

public SliderField( Bitmap thumb
            , Bitmap sliderBackground
            , Bitmap sliderBackgroundFocus
            , int numStates
            , int initialState
            , int xLeftBackMargin
            , int xRightBackMargin )
{
    this( thumb, sliderBackground, sliderBackgroundFocus, numStates, initialState, xLeftBackMargin, xRightBackMargin, FOCUSABLE );
}

public SliderField( Bitmap thumb
            , Bitmap sliderBackground
            , Bitmap sliderBackgroundFocus
            , int numStates
            , int initialState
            , int xLeftBackMargin
            , int xRightBackMargin
            , long style )
{
    super( style );

    if( initialState > numStates || numStates < 2 ){
    }
    _imageThumb = thumb;
    _imageSlider = sliderBackground;
    _imageSliderFocus = sliderBackgroundFocus;
    _numStates = numStates;
    setState( initialState );

    _xLeftBackMargin = xLeftBackMargin;
    _xRightBackMargin = xRightBackMargin;

    _rop = _imageSlider.hasAlpha() ? Graphics.ROP_SRC_ALPHA : Graphics.ROP_SRC_COPY;

    _thumbWidth = thumb.getWidth();
    _thumbHeight = thumb.getHeight();
    initBitmaps();
}              
public SliderField( Bitmap thumb
            , Bitmap sliderBackground
            , int numStates
            , int initialState
            , int xLeftBackMargin
            , int xRightBackMargin
            , int[] colours
            , int[] selectColours )
{
    this(thumb, sliderBackground, sliderBackground, numStates, initialState, xLeftBackMargin, xRightBackMargin, FOCUSABLE );

    if( colours.length != numStates+1 ){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    _backgroundColours = colours;
    _backgroundSelectedColours = selectColours;
}
public void initBitmaps()
{
    int height = _imageSlider.getHeight();

    _imageSliderLeft = new Bitmap( _xLeftBackMargin, height );
    _imageSliderCenter = new Bitmap( _imageSlider.getWidth() - _xRightBackMargin - _xLeftBackMargin, height);
    _imageSliderRight = new Bitmap( _xRightBackMargin, height );

    copy( _imageSlider, 0, 0, _xLeftBackMargin, height, _imageSliderLeft );
    copy( _imageSlider, _xLeftBackMargin, 0, _imageSlider.getWidth() - _xRightBackMargin - _xLeftBackMargin, height, _imageSliderCenter);
    copy( _imageSlider, _imageSlider.getWidth() - _xRightBackMargin, 0, _xRightBackMargin, height, _imageSliderRight);

    _imageSliderFocusLeft = new Bitmap( _xLeftBackMargin, height );
    _imageSliderFocusCenter = new Bitmap( _imageSlider.getWidth() - _xRightBackMargin - _xLeftBackMargin, height);
    _imageSliderFocusRight = new Bitmap( _xRightBackMargin, height );

    copy( _imageSliderFocus, 0, 0, _xLeftBackMargin, height, _imageSliderFocusLeft );
    copy( _imageSliderFocus, _xLeftBackMargin, 0, _imageSlider.getWidth() - _xRightBackMargin - _xLeftBackMargin, height, _imageSliderFocusCenter);
    copy( _imageSliderFocus, _imageSlider.getWidth() - _xRightBackMargin, 0, _xRightBackMargin, height, _imageSliderFocusRight);
}
private void copy(Bitmap src, int x, int y, int width, int height, Bitmap dest) {
    int[] argbData = new int[width * height];
    src.getARGB(argbData, 0, width, x, y, width, height);
    for(int tx = 0; tx < dest.getWidth(); tx += width) {
        for(int ty = 0; ty < dest.getHeight(); ty += height) {
            dest.setARGB(argbData, 0, width, tx, ty, width, height);
        }
    }
}
public void setState(int newState) {
    if( newState > _numStates ){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } else {
        _currentState = newState;
        invalidate();
    }
}
public int getState() {
    return _currentState;
}
public int getNumStates() {
    return _numStates;
}
public int getColour() {
    if(_backgroundSelectedColours != null) {
        return _backgroundSelectedColours[getState()];
    }
    return 0x000000;
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return _totalWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return _totalHeight;
}
protected void layout( int width, int height ) {
    if (width < 0 || height < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    _totalWidth = width;
    _totalHeight = Math.max(_imageSlider.getHeight(), _imageThumb.getHeight());

    setExtent( _totalWidth, _totalHeight );
}

public void paint( Graphics g )
{
    int sliderHeight = _imageSlider.getHeight();
    int sliderBackYOffset = ( _totalHeight - sliderHeight ) >> 1;
    int backgroundColor = _defaultBackgroundColour;
    if( _backgroundSelectedColours != null || _backgroundColours != null ) {

        if( _selected ) {
            backgroundColor = _backgroundSelectedColours != null ? _backgroundSelectedColours[getState()] : _defaultSelectColour;
        } else if(g.isDrawingStyleSet(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS)) {
            backgroundColor = _backgroundColours != null ? _backgroundColours[getState()] : _defaultHoverColour;
        } else {
            backgroundColor = _defaultBackgroundColour;
        }
    }
    g.setColor( backgroundColor );
    g.fillRect( 1, sliderBackYOffset + 1, _totalWidth - 2, sliderHeight - 2 );

    if(g.isDrawingStyleSet(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS)) {    
        paintSliderBackground( g, _imageSliderFocusLeft, _imageSliderFocusCenter, _imageSliderFocusRight );
    } else {
        paintSliderBackground( g, _imageSliderLeft, _imageSliderCenter, _imageSliderRight );
    }
    int thumbXOffset = ( ( _totalWidth - _thumbWidth ) * _currentState ) / _numStates;
    g.drawBitmap( thumbXOffset, ( _totalHeight - _thumbHeight ) >> 1, _thumbWidth, _thumbHeight, _imageThumb, 0, 0 );
}

private void paintSliderBackground( Graphics g, Bitmap left, Bitmap middle, Bitmap right ) 
{
    int sliderHeight = _imageSlider.getHeight();
    int sliderBackYOffset = ( _totalHeight - sliderHeight ) >> 1;
    g.drawBitmap( 0, sliderBackYOffset, _xLeftBackMargin, sliderHeight, left, 0, 0 );
    g.tileRop( _rop, _xRightBackMargin, sliderBackYOffset, _totalWidth - _xLeftBackMargin - _xRightBackMargin, sliderHeight, middle, 0, 0 );
    g.drawBitmap( _totalWidth - _xRightBackMargin, sliderBackYOffset, _xRightBackMargin, sliderHeight, right, 0, 0 );
}

public void paintBackground( Graphics g ) 
{
}

protected void drawFocus( Graphics g, boolean on )
{
    boolean oldDrawStyleFocus = g.isDrawingStyleSet( Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS );
    try {
        if( on ) {
            g.setDrawingStyle( Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS, true );
        }
        paint( g );
    } finally {
        g.setDrawingStyle( Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS, oldDrawStyleFocus );
    }
}
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message)
{
    boolean isConsumed = false;
    boolean isOutOfBounds = false;
    int x = message.getX(1);
    int y = message.getY(1);
    if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x > getExtent().width || y > getExtent().height) {
        isOutOfBounds = true;
    }
    switch(message.getEvent()) {
        case TouchEvent.CLICK:
        case TouchEvent.MOVE:
            if(isOutOfBounds) return true; 
            _selected = true; 

            int stateWidth = getExtent().width / _numStates;
            int numerator = x / stateWidth;
            int denominator = x % stateWidth;
            if( denominator > stateWidth / 2 ) {
                numerator++;
            }
            _currentState = numerator;
            invalidate();

            isConsumed = true;
            break;
        case TouchEvent.UNCLICK:
            if(isOutOfBounds) {
                _selected = false; 
                return true;
            }
            _selected = false; 
            stateWidth = getExtent().width / _numStates;
            numerator = x / stateWidth;
            denominator = x % stateWidth;
            if( denominator > stateWidth / 2 ) {
                numerator++;
            }
            _currentState = numerator;
            invalidate();
            fieldChangeNotify(0);
            isConsumed = true;
            break;
    }
    return isConsumed;
}
protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time) 
{
    if( _selected )
    {
        if(dx > 0 || dy > 0) {
            incrementState();
            fieldChangeNotify( 0 );
            return true;
        } else if(dx < 0 || dy < 0) {
            decrementState();
            fieldChangeNotify( 0 );
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.navigationMovement( dx, dy, status, time);
}
public void decrementState() {
    if(_currentState > 0) {
        _currentState--;
        invalidate();
    }
}
public void incrementState() {
    if(_currentState < _numStates) {
        _currentState++;
        invalidate();
    }
}
protected boolean invokeAction(int action) {
    switch(action) {
        case ACTION_INVOKE: {
            toggleSelected();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
protected boolean keyChar( char key, int status, int time ) {
    if( key == Characters.SPACE || key == Characters.ENTER ) {
        toggleSelected();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
protected boolean trackwheelClick( int status, int time ) {
    if( isEditable() ) {
        toggleSelected();
        return true;
    }
    return super.trackwheelClick(status, time);
}
private void toggleSelected() {
    _selected = !_selected;
    invalidate();
}
public void setDirty( boolean dirty )
{  
}
public void setMuddy( boolean muddy )
{ 
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the code below, you will get your actual requirement,you can get the slider **current value** into your screen class by invoking getValue() method on sliderfield reference..

Implement **FieldChangeListener** interface and try to override **fieldChanged()** method.

Use **HorizontalFieldManager** class and **setStatus()** method, 
if you want to display your slider bar at bottom of your screen,other wise you can display it normally.

Here the Code:

```
    public class SliderScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
private SliderField slider;
 private HorizontalFieldManager hm;

public SliderField(){

slider = new SliderField(
                    Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_thumb_normal.png"),
                    Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_progress_normal.png"),
                    Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_base_normal.png"),
                    Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_thumb_focused.png"),
                    Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_progress_focused.png"),
                    Bitmap.getBitmapResource("slider2_base_focused.png"), 8, 4,
                    8, 8, FOCUSABLE);

            slider.setChangeListener(this);
            hm = new HorizontalFieldManager();


            hm.add(slider);

            setStatus(hm);

}



public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        try {

            if (field == slider) {
                int value = slider.getValue();

            }

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your original answer was OK; the latest one changes your link to a blog post you wrote in order to link to your blog from this answer, and you did not include a disclosure that you were linking to your own blog. I've removed the link, since it violates the rules.

Answer (score 1):

I have done simple example of how to use this code,Check it

```
    public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener//,FocusChangeListener
{
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    public MyScreen()
    {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen       
        setTitle("MyTitle");

        SliderField slider;

        slider = new SliderField( 
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_thumb_normal.png" ),  Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_progress_normal.png" ),  Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_base_normal.png" ),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_thumb_focused.png" ), Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_progress_focused.png" ), Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_base_focused.png"),
            Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_thumb_pressed.png" ), Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_progress_pressed.png" ), Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "slider_base_pressed.png"),
            10, 0, 12, 12, FOCUSABLE );
        slider.setPadding( 20, 20, 20, 20 );
        slider.setBackground( BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground( 0xD3D3D3 ) );
        slider.setChangeListener(this);
        //slider.focusChangeNotify(0);
        add( slider );




    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(field instanceof SliderField)
        {
            SliderField temp = (SliderField)field;
            System.out.println("Temp value is"+temp.getValue());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: how to reduce the width of this slider bar?it was occupying full screen width?

Comment: in layout method of sliderField, assign width = Display.getWidth()/2(whatever you require),you will get ur required size

Comment: hm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
hm.add(playimg_btn);   
hm.add(slider);
setStatus(hm);   
if i place like this the image button is occupying some space of slider at left side on my screen,how can i avoid this?

Comment: IT works properly for me.I dont understand what you are trying to acheive

Comment: actually if i use getwidth()/2 in layout(),i'm able to display slider half of of my screen

Comment: hm = new HorizontalFieldManager(); hm.add(playimg_btn); hm.add(slider); setStatus(hm); if i place like this the image button is occupying some space of slider at left side on my screen

Comment: you want the size of slider to be reduced,so it was done,To postion it place in which you need ,you want to layout the position for slider and assign the position and the width of slider based on our requirements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18220/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-ragi-and-rakesh)